# Django - can we make a model inherit itself?

Tags: django, django-models

I wonder whether we can make a model that have a child inheriting the same class like:

```
class A(models.Model):
    #something
class B(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #and some B will have class B as a child
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a self-referential or recursive model:

```py
class B(models.Model):
    ...
    child = models.ForeignKey('B', ... )
```

The key is to put the referenced model in quotes, which lets Django get around the issue of referring to a model before it's defined.

Another option is to use `self` instead, again in quotes:

```py
    child = models.ForeignKey('self', ... )
```